# A sequence of closed sets with union equal to the subset $[0,1]\times (0,1)$ of the unit square with lexicographic topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let $I=[0,1]$. Recall the lexicographic order on $I^2$ is the binary relation $\prec$ satisfying $x=(x_1,x_2)\prec (y_1,y_2)=y$ if and only if $x_1<y_1$ or [$x_1=y_1$ and $x_2<y_2$], and the order topology $\tau_\prec$ has subbase equal to the collection of open intervals of $(I,\prec)$.

I wish to know why the following collection of (closed) sets does not  have union equal to the open subset $[0,1]\times (0,1)$ of $I^2$.

For $n> 2$ in $\mathbb Z_+$, let $F_n=\{x: \frac{1}{n}\leq x_2\leq 1-\frac{1}{n}\}$.

I understand that, for each such $n$, $F_n$ is closed by virtue of the fact that it is the closure of the open set $I\times \left(\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$. (The latter is open because it is the union of open intervals $\{x_1\}\times \left(\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$.)

Furthermore, I understand that, since $F_n\subset F_{n+1}$, the union $F_\infty=\bigcup_1^\infty F_n$ is the set $I\times (0,1)$. My reasoning for this is the following: for each $x=(x_1,x_2)\in I^2$ such that $0<x_2<1$, there exists $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<x_2<1-\frac{1}{n}$ and so $x\in F_n$; and if $x_2=0,1$, then $x$ belongs to the complement of $F_n$ for every $n$, so that $x\in I^2-F_\infty$.

What am I missing? (For if there is no mistake in my reasoning, then $I\times (0,1)$ is a countable union of closed sets (an F-sigma set) and this would contradict the claim that the complement of $I\times (0,1)$ (Double arrow space) is not a G-delta subset of $I^2$.)

ps. Please don't point me to [Dan Ma's](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/10/07/the-lexicographic-order-and-the-double-arrow-space/) site, I don't see why the arguments that appear there negate the above construction. I have also looked at p.77 of "The encyclopedia of Topology" of Hart, Nagata and Vaughan. They state that $I\times (0,1)$ is not an F-sigma, but their argument only points to an (unsolved) exercise in Engelking's book "General Topology".

Comment: $F_n$ isn't automatically closed. The union $\cup_{x_1\in[0,1]} (\frac1n, 1-\frac1n)$ is uncountable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $F_n$'s are not closed, since their complement is not open. As an example, take
$$F_4 = I \times \left( \frac{1}{4}, \frac{3}{4} \right)$$

Then the point $(\frac{1}{2}, 1) \notin F_4$, however every basic open neighbourhood of $(\frac{1}{2}, 1)$ intersects $F_4$. So $(\frac{1}{2}, 1) \in \overline{F_4}$.

Answer (score 1):

None of your sets $F_n$ is closed. They all contain $F_2=[0,1]\times\left\{\frac12\right\}$, whose closure is

$$F_2\cup\Big((0,1]\times\{0\}\Big)\cup\Big([0,1)\times\{1\}\Big)\;.$$

Note that this is not contained in $[0,1]\times(0,1)$.

Comment: And by this argument, the union $A_3$ of $F_2$ and the double arrow space $A$ is not perfectly normal, for every open neighbourhood of $A$ (which is closed in $A_3$ because $A_3- F_2=A$ and $F_2$ is open) contains all but the left-most and right-most elements of $F_2$. That is surprising. Thanks to you and @Crostul.

Comment: @Patrick: You're welcome.